# Suppress / catch / trap error message on failed fork open() in Perl

Tags: perl

Consider:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $command = "nosuchcommand"

my $rc = open( my $fh, "-|", "$command" );

if ( ! defined( $rc ) )
{
    print "My own error message\n";
}
else
{
    system( "ps -p $rc" );
}
```

Expected output:

```
My own error message
```

Observed output:

```
Can't exec "nosuchcommand": No such file or directory at ./mcre line 8.
My own error message
```

**How can I catch / trap / suppress the error message generated by Perl on a failing open-pipe** (in favor of my own error handling)?

Further observations:

- If I `open( my $fh, "-|", "$command 2>&1" );`, I get the expected output. But in case of **success** of `$command`, I would get the `STDERR` of `$command` mixed into `STDOUT`, and I don't want that.
- If I `open( my $fh, "-|", "$command 2>/dev/null" );`, I get this:

```
    PID TTY          TIME CMD
  15143 pts/0    00:00:00 sh <defunct>
```

So the *specific* redirecion of `2>/dev/null` (instead of `2>&1`) changed the return value of `open`... this was somewhat surprising, but is not the core of my question.

**On IPC::Run**

This has been suggested in two answers by now. I understand that it might be the "correct" answer in the general case, but would *really* prefer not to (as `IPC::Run` is not an option for me on one very significant target platform that comes without it and does not offer an easy way to install it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Can't exec "nosuchcommand": No such file or directory at ./mcre line 8.
```

This line is actually a "warning", enabled by `use warnings;`. From [perldiag](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag):

> Can't exec "%s": %s

> (W exec) A system(), exec(), or piped open call could not execute the named program for the indicated reason. Typical reasons include: the permissions were wrong on the file, the file wasn't found in $ENV{PATH}, the executable in question was compiled for another architecture, or the #! line in a script points to an interpreter that can't be run for similar reasons. (Or maybe your system doesn't support #! at all.)

Now, `use warnings;` is *highly* recommended, so just removing it entirely is not a "solution". But it is possible to disable warnings within a given scope via `no warnings <category>`. So, to suppress that particular message:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $command = "nosuchcommand";
my @args = ();
my $rc;
my $fh;

{
    no warnings qw( exec );
    my $rc = open( my $fh, "-|", "$command", @args );
}

if ( ! defined( $rc ) )
{
    print "My own error message: $!\n";
}
```

Output:

```
My own error message: No such file or directory
```

The part of the error message generated by the underlying shell ("No such file or directory") is in the `$!` special variable. Note that you should be using the four-parameter version of `open` (with an empty LIST if need be, as pictured above). Perl has different methods of executing external commands, one going through `/bin/sh -c` (and not being under control of the `exec` warning), and the other through `execvp` (and **being** under control of said warning). The four-parameter version of `open` ensures that Perl will use the latter.

Answer (score 2):

That message doesn't come from Perl, but from the shell you launched to execute your shell command.<sup>[1]</sup> That's because

```perl
open( my $fh, "-|", $shell_command )
```

is equivalent to

```perl
open( my $fh, "-|", "/bin/sh", "-c", $shell_command )
```

As you suggested, you could redirect STDERR using `2>/dev/null`, but that will also silence errors from the program (when a valid program is used).

Here's what you could do:

```perl
use IPC::Run qw( run );

my @cmd = ( $prog, @args );

eval { run \@cmd };
if ( $@ ) {
   die( "Problem creating child: $@" );
}
elsif ( $? & 0x7F ) {
   die( "Child died from signal ".( $? & 0x7F )."\n" );
}
elsif ( $? >> 8 ) {
   die( "Child exited with error ".( $? >> 8 )."\n" );
}
```

If you want even more control, you'll need to implement things yourself. The source of IPC::Open3's `open3` would be a good start.

---

1. Except Perl optimizes the use of the shell away for simple shell commands, so the message actually does come from Perl. But this is not a useful distinction here.

Comment: I had hoped I could stay away from Open3 / Run and not have to consider blocking issues. Seems like you can't have your cake and eat it.

Comment: ??? IPC::Run doesn't cause blocking issues; it solves them.

Comment: Might be, I could not determine that from a quick look at the docs. Anyway, IPC::Run is not an option for me anyways as it does not ship with one of my target platforms. {shrug} I'd been hoping there was something simple that could be done with the ˋopenˋ call.

Comment: Re "*I'd been hoping there was something simple that could be done with the ˋopenˋ call.*", Well, yeah. You posted it yourself.  You can use `open( my $fh, "-|", "$command 2>/dev/null" )`. But like I said, that will hide the command's error messages as well.

Comment: Turns out the message *is* generated by Perl, and can easily be suppressed. Thanks anyway, and please accept my apology for being overly grumpy yesterday.

Comment: Re "*Turns out the message is generated by Perl*", As mentioned, Perl will emulate the shell for some commands. So whether the message is from Perl or not depends on whether the command triggers the optimization or not. So you can't count on that.

Comment: Since the warning is generated by Perl in the first place, yes you can -- unless Perl is so broken that it *doesn't generate its own warning* when it takes the shortcut.

Comment: Backwards. It only issues the error message when it acts as a shell (i.e. when it "takes the shortcut"). When it doesn't act as the shell, the actual shell generates the error message. Try `my $command = 'nosuchcommand';` (optimized) and `my $command = 'nosuchcommand "foo bar"';` (not optimized)

Answer (score 2):

As for redirection in the shell, we can redirect `STDERR` separately to a file

```
command 2> stderr.out
```

(as well as any file descriptors)  
This leaves `STDOUT` going out, as you want in a pipe-open, or redirect it as well (`cmd > stdout.out 2> stderr.out`).

The mechanism can be used in Perl code since with shell metacharacters in the command (like redirection symbols) a shell is used.<sup>†</sup>  Perl uses `sh` but that is normally linked to another shell so check which shell is used instead of `sh` in your distribution.  (Or run via `bash` explicitly.)

An example

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $errfile = 'err.out';
my $pid = open my $fh, '-|', "ls *txt nofile 2> $errfile" 
    // die "fork failed: $!";        
print "stdout: $_" while <$fh>;
close $fh or say "Exit: ", $? >> 8;
    
if (-z $errfile) {
    unlink $errfile or warn "Can't unlink $errfile: $!"
}   
else { # there was STDERR stream printed, see it
    print "error-file:\n", 
        my $err = do { local (@ARGV, $/) = $errfile; <> };
    # investigate $err more closely?
}
```

So this does capture the `STDERR` stream, and on its own, but then there is a file to deal with.<sup>‡</sup>

The `open`'s return is the pid of the child process (which here is the shell, regardless of whether the command can then be started by it), unless `fork` itself failed.<sup>§</sup>  Checking  [close](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/close) is the way to see how things went and get a hint of possible problems -- the command couldn't be started, it reports a non-zero status, etc

> If the filehandle came from a piped open, `close` returns false if one of the other syscalls involved fails or if its program exits with non-zero status. ...

Here the command (`ls`) is started successfully and prints the `*txt` files if any, and the exit code (`2` on my system). The message that would come out on the `STDERR` stream about a non-existent `nofile` goes instead into the `err.out` file.

In case when the command itself fails to start only the exit code is printed (`127`), while the `STDERR` message again winds up in the file.

We can't directly tell whether the message redirected to a file is about the program (that doesn't exist or failed to start) or from the program itself as it prints to `STDERR`.  But we do keep that error in a file so that it can be investigated more closely, unlike when it's sent to `/dev/null`.

Finally, I too would recommend [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run) instead.  Basic uses are trivial, while it is almost a mini-shell if you need it to be.

---

<sup>†</sup> External commands are started either by starting a shell and passing it the string with the command and arguments, or by using one of `execvp` functions to start the command directly.  If the command has no shell "metacharacters"  (redirections, globbing, quoting, etc) the process is normally optimized by avoiding the shell. This can be ensured by the syntax, see [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system) and [exec](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/exec).  Otherwise the shell is started so to be able to perform indicated actions.

This clearly makes a difference: with the shell the command undergoes its syntax rules as well, we may get shell's messages, in pipe-open a process *is* forked for the shell (`fork` normally doesn't fail) and then another for the command, etc.  With no shell we can get perl's messages about the (failed) command.  In either case we may also get messages from the program itself.  What went down is not normally easily disentangled without getting into details or using libraries (and getting into details).

<sup>‡</sup>  I read the file in one statement (and save it into a variable) with builtin tools since an issue with non-core modules was mentioned.  If installing software is actually not a problem, there are good libraries for this.  For instance

```
use Path::Tiny;  # path, slurp

my $err = path($errfile)->slurp;
```

<sup>§</sup>  An [example in open docs](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open#Opening-a-filehandle-into-a-command) implies that a command that can't start results in `open` returning `false`.  That is valid only for commands which don't involve shell metacharacters and so are started directly -- so if they fail to start there is indeed no process.

Also see this topic [in perlipc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc#Using-open()-for-IPC), with a more accurate error message in examples.

Comment: @DevSolar  fyi -- I edited a lot since posting, and have just added a footnote on how external programs get started in Perl, what is relevant here -- in general we dont' know where messages come from. It could be the interpreter (perl), or the shell, and/or the started program.